# SuperUser bug: badge border is cut off in Chrome and Opera, fine in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-deferred

I just noticed this at the bottom of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/5321/whats-the-most-stupid-thing-youve-experienced-a-technical-impaired-doing-with-a) on SU:

**Chrome 2.0.172.33**
[image: Chrome]

**Firefox 3.5**
[image: Firefox]

**EDIT** Can anyone with Chrome 3 take a look and tell us if it's wrong there too?

Comment: 2+ year later, still not fix?

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4824/favorite-ignore-tags-right-hand-side-of-box-is-cut-off-at-line-ends-in-opera-o / 10k+ only

Answer (score 2):

That's actually the way the browser renders rounded corners. It can be fixed by using a background image instead of `border-radius`, but it will most likely be "fixed" in Chrome sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

In **Opera** 9.61, the tags look like this:

[image]

Comment: The square corners are because Opera has no support for border-radius. Though I don't understand why then  the borders are in seperate elements (causing them to wrap seperately) since they're using border-radius.

Answer (score 1):

The border looks fine in other contexts (not at the end of the line in the header at the bottom of the page). So this is a bug in Chrome - likely miscalculating the clipping region.

**Edit:** Just checked this in the latest Chromium nightly - it's even *worse*! Ha!