# Small tag display bug in Safari?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SuperUser bug: badge border is cut off in Chrome, fine in Firefox](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/200/superuser-bug-badge-border-is-cut-off-in-chrome-fine-in-firefox)

In Safari 5.1 and Chrome 12.x and 14.x the favorite and ignored tags look cut off. It doesn't affect functionality, and it's purely aesthetic. It sort of occurs in stack overflow for me too.

[image]

Anyone else experience this problem?
Turning off Javascript fixes the display error for me, so I don't think it's a problem with CSS, which means I don't think it's a duplicate of the CSS-border issue described in the "Possible Duplicate."

Comment: I haven't observed this in 5.0.5; bug in Lion's Safari (or WebKit)?

Comment: Maybe it's Lion/Safari's fault.

Comment: It's fine to post it here

Comment: longstanding webkit issue; works in IE9 and Firefox, etc

Comment: @JeffAtwood the point still remains: Chrome and Safari are on your "supported browsers" list, and this problem exists. Saying "well it works in the other browsers, so we're not going to try to fix it" is a bit of a cop-out. Yes, it's been an issue for years. Just because you've been ignoring it for years doesn't make it better.

Comment: @nhinkle it's valid CSS -- there's nothing to fix. This is like arguing that rounded corners are broken in IE8 because they render square..

Comment: @Jeff I don't think it's the CSS - because turning off javascript makes it display right for me. I think it's a different problem from the one marked duplicate.

Comment: So, can we reopen this?