# Favorite tags in Chrome isn't displaying correctly

Tags: bug, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SuperUser bug: badge border is cut off in Chrome, fine in Firefox](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/200/superuser-bug-badge-border-is-cut-off-in-chrome-fine-in-firefox)

Chrome displays Favorite Tag on home page like this:

[image]

I have confirm this on Chrome v12, v13, and v14 on two different computers.

Comment: Same issue with Safari on OS X.