# Tags are not appearing properly in Tags Field

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags

Why this tags are not displaying properly on IE8?

Whether this is an known issue?

[image]

Comment: What build of IE 8 are you using?

Comment: You mean version, 8.0.7601.XXXXXX

Comment: Yes, the XXXXXX part.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: sorry am not at my PC to say remaining part of version that is `XXXXXX`. Now I have seen one more thing, on IE 8 version **"8.0.7600"** it is appearing properly.

Comment: Yes I have cleared cache but still same.

Comment: Any ideas, why it is behaving different on two different version of IE8?

Comment: Any suggestion on this issue @DanielBeck?

Comment: No idea. Just wanted to get as much information as possible early. IE has compatibility mode, maybe that one is triggered for some reason.

Comment: [Possibly related](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/200/superuser-bug-badge-border-is-cut-off-in-chrome-fine-in-firefox).

Comment: fwiw the tags section rendered in IE7 looks the same as in screenshot

Comment: ohh ok then it seems there is browser compatibility issue on IE7 & for few version of IE8.

Comment: Reason for `status-declined` is probably that IE 8 [is not a supported browser](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).